# How would you chain Math.abs and toLocaleString() together in the same line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, kendo-ui

I have some some data in the form of a large number, and **I want the value to be absolute** and I **want the value to have commas.**

I'm working with Kendo UI which does `kendo.toString()`, but as far as I can tell the formatting's basically the same thing as `.toLocaleString`. Kendo uses templates in order to display data results, as seen below.

#### JS snippet:

```
function createWOffChart(payload, stdYAxis) {
        let i = Math.abs(payload[0].woffamt.toFixed(2));
        let j = Math.abs(payload[0].wuwdamt.toFixed(2));
        let k = Number(i) + Number(j);
        let total = k.toLocaleString();

        $("div[report='woff']").kendoChart({
            dataSource: {
                data: payload
                // template: "#= kendo.toString(value/1000000) #"
            },
            legend: {
                visible: true
            },
            schema: {
                data: "value"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column",
                stack: true
            },
            chartArea: {
                width: 260,
                height: 350
            },
            series: [{
                name: "WOffAmt",
                field: "woffamt", // req
                color: "#4dc3a1",
                template: "#= Math.abs(value) #"
            }, {
                name: "WUWDAmt",
                field: "wuwdamt", // req
                color: "#5d5348",
                template: "#= Math.abs(value) #"
                // template: 
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "#= Math.abs(kendo.toString(value/1000000)) #" // ------ this did not work
                },
                reverse: true // orients chart right side up
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "#= series.name #: #= Math.abs(value) #" // ------ this is where I want the chaining to happen
            }
        });
        console.log(payload);
        console.log(kendo.toString(payload[0].wuwdamt));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you need to get the absolute value first and then use the `toString` method.

```
kendo.toString(Math.abs(value / 1000000))
```

Comment: Hey Nina, it turned out that `toLocaleString()` worked and not `kendo.toString`...don't ask me why -_- But your comment led me in the right direction, so thank you!